# Rails Migration: Bigint on PostgreSQL seems to be failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, migration, bigint

Trying to create a table with a bigint column creates a standard integer column instead. What could be going wrong? I don't know where to start looking.

I'm using this in the migration:

```
create_table :table_name do |t|
  t.integer :really_big_int, limit: 8
end
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2, PostgreSQL 9.0.3 and Rails 3.0.9. I've dropped the database and ran the migrations several times and it still doesn't create the bigint column.

Comment: Very strange. How are you determining that it creates an integer column—by looking at schema.rb or your PG schema?

Comment: I'm checking on both places. I just solved it using a string column, although I'm still really curious to know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Any update on this, it seems that :limit => 8 is not creating bigint column in Postgres.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For some reason the create table doesn't like bigint. You can, however do it with add_columm using the bigint data type:

```
add_column :table_name, :really_big_int, :bigint
```

Then you don't need that limit stuff.

Comment: Using Rails 3.2.2 and the `pg` gem (version 0.14.0) this works. Haven't checked in older versions.

Answer (score 23):

This works in Rails 4

```
t.column :really_big_int, :bigint
```

Answer (score 8):

Rails 5.0.0.1 it works:

```
  def change
    create_table :huge do |t|  
      t.integer :big_bastard, limit: 8
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

In rails 4.2 + you can use like:

```
create_table :table_name do |t|
   t.bigint :really_big_int
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a bigint using `t.column`.  This is useful if you want to control the column order in the table.

```
create_table :table_name do |t|
  t.string :other_column
  t.column :really_big_int, :bigint
  .
  .
  t.timestamps
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.12 with pg gem version 0.15.1 (x86-mingw32).