# What is default integer limit in PostrgreSQL database for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, limits

What is default integer limit in PostrgreSQL database for Rails 3?

That's the question.

Comment: You just want to know what integer range is valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, *Rails* will use PostgreSQL's [integer type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE), which has a range of -2147483648 to +2147483647.

Comment: Can you get it to use a bigint?  That's 2^63-1 max.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe This is an old question, but here's a link that shows how to change the column type for Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061239/rails-migration-bigint-on-postgresql-seems-to-be-failing