# Using bigint in PostgreSQL and SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, bigint

How would I specify `bigint` in a `create_table` for PostgreSQL and SQLite in a rails schema file?

I've looked at the data types to see that there is a carry over between the two and checked their capacities [here](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_int64) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC).

I then saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061239/rails-migration-bigint-on-postgresql-seems-to-be-failing) question and I was wondering if there really wasn't any way to create the `bigint` inside the `create_table` schema.

Also, I am not necessarily looking for `bigint`, but rather an 64-bit datatype; signing doesn't matter (I will only be accessing the bits).

Comment: The first question is *why are you trying to use a bitmap inside a relational database?* You can always hammer a square peg into a round hole but it will be messy.

Comment: @muistooshort I just want something that will work on either platform, but I need all 64 bits for my column.

Comment: You misunderstand. I'm questioning your "I will only be accessing the bits" design decision. Is this just an opaque blob of data that the database is just storing or are you expecting to do bit operations inside queries?

Comment: @muistooshort It's just an "opaque blob" of data. I will be doing all bit operations outside of the queries.

Comment: @muistooshort The reason I chose `bigint` is because it seemed to be the only thing that was 8 bytes and was on both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL:

```
create table whatever ( some_column bigint );
```

That's all. But if you want bit operations, it's better to use dedicated data type - namely [bit(n)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-bit.html)

Comment: But would bit be possible in SQLite as well? Also, would that work in a rails schema?

Comment: @RileyE: Not as easy as in Postgres. Postgres `BIT` or `VARBIT` type can be of unlimited length (like in megabytes) and natively supports operations like `&`, `|` and their aggregate equivalents `bit_and`, `bit_or`. Nothing like that exists for SQLite - but you can re-implement it, I guess.

Comment: @RileyE This will also work in SQLite due to its [dynamic type system](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: @mvp Okay. That's good to know, but I guess I may have to stick with the cross-platform types, right? Thank you for that tasty tid `BIT` of information :)

Comment: @CL. So, if I stay with a regular implementation of `bigint`, then I should be fine? But what about the issues with it not working in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061239/rails-migration-bigint-on-postgresql-seems-to-be-failing?lq=1)?