# Rails migration for BigInt fails when using Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, bigint

I'm trying to get a column in my database to use bigint as the type.

I have tried several combinations already including these with no luck:

```
add_column :my_table, :my_field, :bigint
add_column :my_table, :my_field, :bigint, limit: 8
add_column :my_table, :my_field, :integer, limit: 8
```

I think part of the issue is that this is not just a Rails migration for a DB column to be bigint, but it also needs to work with PostGres.

Comment: are you using the pg gem?

Comment: did using t.integer with a limit or t.column in a migration (as suggested in my answer) solve the issue?

Comment: Not quite yet. May need to simply set the value of my_field as a string instead of integer. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: setting it as an integer with a limit of 8 should work. can you post your whole migration file?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a couple of ways to do this:

**1. Using a limit of 8 with the integer type.**

```
create_table 'example' do |t|
  t.integer :my_field, :limit => 8
end
```

See [this page](http://makandracards.com/makandra/15027-how-to-create-columns-like-bigint-or-longtext-in-rails-migrations-and-what-limit-means-for-column-migrations) for more information on using limits to set integer sizing in Rails.

**2. Using t.column with a bigint type**

For some reason the create table doesn't like bigint. You can, however do it with add_columm using the bigint data type:

```
add_column :table_name, :really_big_int, :bigint
```

In Rails 4 with the `pg` gem this works:

```
class CreateDemo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :my_table do |t|
      t.column :my_field, :bigint
    end
  end
end
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061239/rails-migration-bigint-on-postgresql-seems-to-be-failing) for more details on that.

This answer assumes that you're using the `pg` gem in your Rails project and that you've got a postgres database created and accessible in your development environment (specified in `app/config/database.yml`).