# Bigint column for postgresql not work in my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 5.2.3 + postgresql 11.5 + gem 'pg', '1.1.4'.
My first migration:

```
class CreateTmpUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table(:tmp_users) do |t|
      t.integer :external_id
      ...
    end
    add_index ...
  end
end
```

second migration:

```
class MigrateToRails52 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    change_column :tmp_users, :external_id, :bigint
...
end
```

schema.db after rails db:migrate:

```
create_table "tmp_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "external_id"
    ...
end
```

schema.db after rails db:schema:dump

```
create_table "tmp_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "external_id"
    ...
end
```

inside pgadmin I see: Type: bigint

TmpUser.inspect gives:

```
TmpUser(id: integer, external_id: integer, name: strin...
```

Save through ActiveRecord gives:

```
TmpUser.create external_id: 392169714724389808
```

message: 392169714724389808 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4 bytes
error class: ActiveModel::RangeError

I need 8 bytes, but got 4 in validation

Comment: gem 'activerecord-suppress_range_error' - partically solve my problem. There is new one: PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR: value "392169714724389808" is out of range for type integer
gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter:611

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the create table doesn't like bigint. You can, however do it with add_columm using the bigint data type:

```
add_column :table_name, :really_big_int, :bigint
```

Source: - [Rails Migration: Bigint on PostgreSQL seems to be failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061239/rails-migration-bigint-on-postgresql-seems-to-be-failing)

Comment: Now I have database with data, which I don't want destroy.
I have column type bigint in database.
I have migrations history where I can edit change_column to add_column.
I have result schema.db:

     create_table "tmp_users", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.bigint "external_id"
         ...
    end
Additionally rails on init read database to calculate schema.rb and I can remove schema.db whith no affect to my application.
So if I want to setup my model manualy what I must do for this?